# How to update two cells simultaneously, through one or the other?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Excel workbook calculator dependent on a few parameters. I want the client to be able to insert those parameters into an appropriate "client input" cell on every spreadsheet so he doesn't have to jump back and forth between spreadsheets.

Is there a good way to do it? I tried the following scheme, but it's buggy for reasons unknown to me:

- make a VBA module declaring variables to hold my parameters
- initialize them with appropriate initial values on the `Workbook_Open` event
- make the specific sheets write those values into "client input" cells on `Worksheet_Activate` event
- in a `Worksheet_Deactivate` event, if the "client input" cells are different among each other - update the VBA variables

This works sometimes, but not always. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

This is my "GM" Module:

```
Option Explicit

Public perspective As String
Public RSS As String
Public Payback As Double
```

This is my "ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    GM.perspective = Worksheets("Hidden variables").Range("A1").Value
    GM.RSS = Worksheets("Hidden variables").Range("B2").Value
    GM.Payback = Worksheets("Hidden variables").Range("C3").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Close()
    Worksheets("Hidden variables").Range("A1") = GM.perspective
    Worksheets("Hidden variables").Range("B2") = GM.RSS
    Worksheets("Hidden variables").Range("C3") = GM.Payback
End Sub
```

This is in my worksheet 1 (in worksheet 2 there is an analogous code):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
     'SIMULTANEOUS UPDATE p.1
     Worksheets("1").Range("I32") = GM.Payback
     Worksheets("1").Range("I29") = GM.RSS
     Worksheets("1").Range("I26") = GM.perspective
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'BASIC PRICE CALCULATION
     If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
     If Target = Range("I32") _
     Or Target = Range("I29") _
     Or Target = Range("I26") _
     Or Target = Worksheets("Intro").Range("price") _
     Then

    Worksheets("Hidden variables").Range("condition") = 2
        Worksheets("Hidden variables").Range("basic_price") = Worksheets("Intro").Range("price").Value
        Range("M44").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Worksheets("Hidden variables").Range("basic_price")
        If Worksheets("Hidden variables").Range("basic_price").Value < 0 Then
            Range("M46") = "Error"
        Else
            Range("M46") = Worksheets("Hidden variables").Range("basic_price").Value
        End If
    Worksheets("Hidden variables").Range("condition") = 1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
'SIMULTANEOUS UPDATE p.2
        GM.Payback = Worksheets("1").Range("I32").Value
        GM.RSS = Worksheets("1").Range("I29").Value
        GM.perspective = Worksheets("1").Range("I26").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: please show some code and specify where is it

Comment: I believe you just want one cell, or a range of cells that is input. Why wait till worksheet activate and not just write the values to all other cells once the value of the input cells is changed? Look into Worksheet_Change for example.

Comment: @genespos I added the code.

Comment: @Luuklag The problem with Worsheet_Change is that I'm using it already to update the worksheets based on the client input (see my edit). So I tried the approach with `Worksheet_Activate` and `Worksheet_Deactive` to avoid infinite loops. If It weren't for the basic price calculation, that I want to update every time the client changes his input cells, `Worksheet_Change` would work (I used this approach before). So my question is basically is there a simpler, easier, more direct approach without the potential to create infinite loops with my middle subroutine?

Comment: Can't you just insert a formula into the cells of the second worksheet referencing the first?

Comment: You could use a bool global value to indicate if an update is in progress or not.
When you begin your update (in worksheet_change) set this variable to true and a control (before the set to true) "if variable is true, exit sub". You'll avoid an infinite loop

Comment: @Roland I want those cells to be on equal footing: the client should be able to write input to one or the other, and would like the other to be updated.

Comment: @MaximePorté Your idea sound like a really good one. Could you provide me with some details (I'm a newbie in VBA and I'm not sure where I should place the code for changing this bool value to 1 and back to 0)?

Comment: I would still go for the Worksheet_Change but set it so that it only runs when the input cells are changed, therefore you don't result in an infinite loop. Also write this in a separate sub. For some info on how to do these things see: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid infinite loop, you can use a global variable
Outside a function (at the begin of your module)

```
Public isUpdating As Double
```

inside your Worksheet_change

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Check if an update is in progress. If so, exit the change
    if isUpdating then
        exit sub
    end if

    ' Begin of the update
    isUpdating = true

    ' Here your update

    ' End of the update
    isUpdating = false
End sub
```